# Image not loading on click event

Tags: jquery

So I have a click event set up like so and image in it made like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#owl-demo_myteam img").click(function() {

        $("#main").html('<img style="margin:270px auto; width:75px" src="/public/assets/images/loader.gif" />'); 

    });
});
```

Is there a problem with jquery reading the image source in that way? Because loader.gif just doesn't want to be displayed, I always get blank square with a border but if I remove `$("#owl-demo_myteam img").click(function(){})` event loader.gif magicaly appears... I am baffled

EDIT: Strangest thing is if I remove the click event and load the image and then make the event again image displays correctly, then after a while it goes back to blank again

Comment: It is hard to help you without a complete, workable example. What is the HTML?

Comment: let me make a fiddle

Comment: nothing is technically wrong, have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/gbtdey2v/ what's your console saying when you click the image?

Comment: my console is clean, maybe its my enviroments fault I am coding in codeigniter, maybe a mismatch with path or something

Comment: strange! nothing looks wrong with your jquery so i'd say start to look at image paths etc in your environment...

Comment: strangest thing is if I remove the click event and load the image and then make the event again image displays correctly, then after a while it goes back to blank again

Comment: try you code in a fiddle to make sure it's an environment issue. If it's not, let us check your fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the image in the place with css "display:none" and when you want the image to appear you just make .show() to the element that was "display:none". In this way the image loads on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbtdey2v/), something is wrong with your styling on the image that's failing to show. Remove at least the margin and it should show up.

```
$("#main").html('<img style="" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=loaded" />');
```